# .htaccess rewrite rule not working (rewrite module enabled)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get the value of `$_GET['pid']` on the `products.php` page, looks like it's not working for me, any help would be appreciated.

`.htaccess` rewrite rule as follows

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)$ /products.php?pid=$1 [NC,L]
```

index.php

```
<?php 
$i=1;
while($i <= 10){
    echo '<a href="products.php?pid='.$i.'">Products '.$i.'</a><br />';
    $i++;
}
?>
```

products.php

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_GET['pid'])){
    header('location : index.php');
}
else if(isset($_GET['pid'])){
    echo 'Product id - '.$_GET['pid'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Can someone please take a look at the code and tell me where am i wrong?

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you directly access `example.com/products.php?pid=123`? Note that `elseif` (no space) is the construct in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the links are not shown correctly? 
Your php file has to output the links, which mod_rewrite "translates" later. See example below:

```
<?php 
$i=1;
while($i <= 10){
echo '<a href="products/'.$i.'">Products '.$i.'</a><br />';
$i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: FlorianR, yes links are not showing correctly. When i try to access the pid variable on products.php page, it gives me an error.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: pid in C:\wamp\www\htaccess\products.php on line 10

Comment: that´s a notice not an error. the rewriterule is correct. You can check your error level perhaps you want to disable notices

Comment: Right, but how do i get the value of pid variable on the same page?

Comment: That wont solve the issue, are you sure the rewrite rule is written properly? Is there any alternate way i can get the value of pid variable on products.php page?

Comment: yes it´s working. just copied your code on my local server

Comment: I have checked the <?php phpinfo(); ?> as well, nothing shows up.

Comment: Don't disable E_NOTICE messages! That is just masking the problem. From the code you have posted you should not be getting an "Undefined index" notice - so there is something else going on here. Your error states line#10 - you don't have 10 lines in the code you have posted?

Comment: on a live server nobody has notices enabled. Come on :) But again the code posted is correct (without notices )

Comment: echo "Product id : ". $_GET['pid']; [Line 10]

Comment: if(isset($_GET['pid'])) echo "Product id : ". $_GET['pid'];

Answer (score 0):

We use Htaccess to rewrite "ugly" URL's to shorter and prettier.In your code, you change your htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ products.php?pid=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Then change your URL's.

```
  <?php 
       $i=1;
       while($i <= 10){
       echo '<a href="products.php/'.$i.'">Products '.$i.'</a><br />';
       $i++;
      }
   ?>
```